# Can I change controlPlaneEndpoint after kubernetes initialization?

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability, kubeadm

I'm new to kubernetes and this is my kubernetes version info

```
kubeadm version: &version.Info{
Major:"1",
Minor:"27", 
GitVersion:"v1.27.3", 
GitCommit:"25b4e43193bcda6c7328a6d147b1fb73a33f1598", 
GitTreeState:"clean", 
BuildDate:"2023-06-14T09:52:26Z", 
GoVersion:"go1.20.5", 
Compiler:"gc", 
Platform:"linux/amd64"
}
```

I want to create a highly available topology, using a [stacked-etcd-topology](https://v1-27.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/ha-topology/#stacked-etcd-topology) form.

Here is my kubeadm init config file

```yaml
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
bootstrapTokens:
- groups:
  - system:bootstrappers:kubeadm:default-node-token
  token: abcdef.0123456789abcdef
  ttl: 24h0m0s
  usages:
  - signing
  - authentication
kind: InitConfiguration
localAPIEndpoint:
  advertiseAddress: 192.168.44.135
  bindPort: 6443
nodeRegistration: 
  criSocket: unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent 
  taints: null
---
apiServer:
  timeoutForControlPlane: 4m0s
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
certificatesDir: /etc/kubernetes/pki
clusterName: kubernetes
controllerManager: {}
dns: {}
etcd:
  local:
    dataDir: /data/paas/etcd
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: 1.27.3
networking:
  dnsDomain: cluster.local
  serviceSubnet: 10.96.0.0/12
  podSubnet: 10.244.0.0/16
scheduler: {}
controlPlaneEndpoint: "192.168.44.135:6443"  # load balancer, first control plane ip
---
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: KubeletConfiguration
cgroupDriver: systemd
---
apiVersion: kubeproxy.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: KubeProxyConfiguration
mode: ipvs
```

I set `controlPlaneEndpoint` to the ip of the first control plane node, because our previous project was running [`kube-vip` as `Daemonset` and using it for load balancing](https://kube-vip.io/docs/installation/daemonset/), and I wanted to configure `controlPlaneEndpoint` later on after installing `kube-vip`.

I don't seem to find anything in the kubernetes documentation about modifying `controlPlaneEndpoint`, how do I accomplish this, if it's not allowed I'll try to install the load balancing earlier.

Looking forward to your help.